# Perform arithemetic operation on np.where()

Tags: python, dataframe

```
A   B   C

0   1   5
5   8   4
6   3   2 
4   7   1 
2   0   8
```

This is my dataFrame.

I want to compare each column with another and store the highest value in a new variable . Hence decide who is the winner

For example. Lets compare column A with column B

```
for i in df.columns[1:]: 
    for j in df.columns[1:]: 
        if i != j:
            np.where(df[i] >= df[j], totalI = totalI+df[i], totalJ=totalJ+df[j])
```

On executing I am getting this error : TypeError: where() got an unexpected keyword argument 'totalI'.

Expected Output When A is compared with B : totalI = 8 and totalJ = 16

I am new to python. I want a solution to store the added values in case of true and false of np.where

Comment: Please add the specific expected output for your example and what you have tried to your question to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have rephrased the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on how to use np.where? That is not how it should be called. Are you trying to do multiple comparisons or are you actually trying to assign values to variables? if the latter is the case, move the assignments out of np.where

Comment: Yes, I did read the documentation. It doesnt allow to assign inside the parameters. Is there a way i can add all the highest values , without assigning np.where() seperatedly to a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are talking about, correct me if I am wrong.

I assume you have a dataframe kind of like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 5], [5, 8, 4], [6, 3, 2], [4, 7, 1], [2, 0, 8]], columns = ["A", "B", "C"])
```

This is what I got from your example dataset.

Then I used `itertools` to come up with as many combinations of the columns `["A", "B", "C"]`, for example `A > B`, `B > A`, like so:

```py
import itertools
combination_columns = list(itertools.permutations(["A", "B", "C"], 2))
```

Then if you iterate through each theorem, and add them up into a dictionary like this:

```py
import numpy as np
totals = {}
for comb in combination_columns:
    totals[f"{comb[0]} > {comb[1]}"] = sum(np.where(df[comb[0]] > df[comb[1]], df[comb[0]], 0))
```

You get this:

```
>>> print(totals)
{'A > B': 8, 'A > C': 15, 'B > A': 16, 'B > C': 18, 'C > A': 13, 'C > B': 13}
```

As you can see your `totalI` is equivalent to `totals['A > B']` and your `totalJ` is equivalent to `totals['B > A']`. Obviously you could use a different naming scheme if it better suited you.

The whole code reads as so:

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 5], [5, 8, 4], [6, 3, 2], [4, 7, 1], [2, 0, 8]], columns = ["A", "B", "C"])
combination_columns = list(itertools.permutations(["A", "B", "C"], 2))

totals = {}
for comb in combination_columns:
    totals[f"{comb[0]} > {comb[1]}"] = sum(np.where(df[comb[0]] > df[comb[1]], df[comb[0]], 0))

print(totals)
```

In relation to your comment it could be rewritten as so:

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 5], [5, 8, 4], [6, 3, 2], [4, 7, 1], [2, 0, 8]], columns = ["A", "B", "C"])
combination_columns = list(itertools.combinations(["A", "B", "C"], 2))

totals = {}
for comb in combination_columns:
    x_vs_y = sum(np.where(df[comb[0]] > df[comb[1]], df[comb[0]], 0))
    y_vs_x = sum(np.where(df[comb[0]] < df[comb[1]], df[comb[1]], 0))
    totals[f"{comb[0]} Vs {comb[1]}"] = comb[0] if x_vs_y > y_vs_x else comb[1]

print(totals)
```

It is not clean but if you want to do your list idea, this is what I came up with:

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 5], [5, 8, 4], [6, 3, 2], [4, 7, 1], [2, 0, 8]], columns = ["A", "B", "C"])
combination_columns = list(itertools.combinations(["A", "B", "C"], 2))

totals = []
for comb in combination_columns:
    x_vs_y = sum(np.where(df[comb[0]] > df[comb[1]], df[comb[0]], 0))
    y_vs_x = sum(np.where(df[comb[0]] < df[comb[1]], df[comb[1]], 0))
    totals.append((comb[0] if x_vs_y > y_vs_x else comb[1]) + ' beats ' + (comb[1] if x_vs_y > y_vs_x else comb[0]))

print(totals)
```

Comment: First of all I thank you for the quick reply. In my case If A is compared with B , then We dont need to compared Visa versa. As we already know the highest among both. I.e B (Order doesn't matter). So my expected o/p is ````['B wins over A': 'B wins over C' : 'A wins over C']````

Comment: Thank you jimbob88. It fixed my the issue.